# Many to many association

Tags: django, foreign-keys, many-to-many, associations

I don't understand why we have to use ManyToManyField to declare a many to many association. To do so, I would create another table with two foreign keys, period!
Here is an example from the doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    extraField = models.DateField()
```

I would just write:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    extraField = models.DateField()
```

Is it correct? What is the difference?

Comment: I'll let someone answer this who is more qualified. Great question.

Comment: The correct way is to do it with the `ManyToManyField` just because it's tedious to make that extra model called `Membership` in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with defining an intermediate model for the relationship. That way you can store extra information on the intermediate model (Membership), like when the person joined the group, or if the membership is still valid. However, most of the time you don't need the extra information and only want to store which person is member of which group. In those cases, you could just use a simple `ManyToManyField`. Django makes it very easy to work with those fields, so you can do `group.members.add(user)` and `group.members.delete(user)`, compare that to:

```
Membership.objects.create(user=user, group=group)
Membership.objects.get(user=user, group=group).delete()
```

Disclaimer: pseudo-code, might not actually work

You can still use ManyToManyField with an intermediate model, this allows for most of the Django ManyToMany conveniences, but with some restrictions:

> Unlike normal many-to-many fields, you can’t use add, create, or assignment (i.e., beatles.members = [...]) to create relationships.
>
> Why? You can’t just create a relationship between a Person and a Group - you need to specify all the detail for the relationship required by the Membership model. The simple add, create and assignment calls don’t provide a way to specify this extra detail. As a result, they are disabled for many-to-many relationships that use an intermediate model. The only way to create this type of relationship is to create instances of the intermediate model.
>
> The remove() method is disabled for similar reasons. However, the clear() method can be used to remove all many-to-many relationships for an instance.
>
> Once you have established the many-to-many relationships by creating instances of your intermediate model, you can issue queries. Just as with normal many-to-many relationships, you can query using the attributes of the many-to-many-related model.
>
> Source: [docs.djangoproject.com](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)

Comment: Ok so it's just a shortcut... What if we want to create the intermediate table (with the foreign keys)... is it still necessary to use ManyToManyField?

Comment: `ManyToManyField(through=...)` is optional if you have the intermediate model created yourself. It still provides you most of the shortcuts, but isn't able to create new relationships. See also my edit.

Comment: I understand now, it's better to use ManyToManyField to get access to the django shortcuts to manipulate the models. Thanks!